# Button and Video not Working in HTML/Bootstrap Section

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website for an organization I am in and I am using `bootstrap` along with my `HTML` for the `CSS`. However, on one page I want to have a `youtube` video linked and a button to an external website.

When I have the code, as seen below, when you click on the video or the button, nothing happens. I have been able to determine that the only aspect that seems to make it work is when I comment out the section for the page. When this is done, the video and button work. However, no other changes work.

Can anyone provide any assistance to make these work? Thanks.

```html
<section class="page-section cta">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-10 mx-auto">
          <div class="cta-inner text-center rounded">
            <h2 class="section-heading mb-5">
      <span class="section-heading-lower">Can't Visit Campus?</span>
      <br>
      <span class="section-heading-upper"><b>Take a Virtual Tour of the Mechanical Engineering Building with our Ambassadors in the Video Below!</span>
      <br>
      </a>
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Y9oIY5Znsi0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
      <br>
      <br>
      <span class="section-heading-upper"><b>Schedule a Virtual Meeting with an Ambassador</span>
      <br>
      <div class="intro-button mx-auto">
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xl" href="(Website link goes here but is removed for privacy)">Sign Up Here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The link should be the parent element. Wrap the outside like this...

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xl" href="(Website link goes here but is removed for privacy)"> <iframe width="560"
    height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Y9oIY5Znsi0" frameborder="0"
    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
  </iframe>
  <br>
  <br>
  <span class="section-heading-upper"><b>Schedule a Virtual Meeting with an Ambassador</span>
  <br>
  <div class="intro-button mx-auto">
    Sign Up Here
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```